# Obj-C to swift in xcode

Tags: swift

I am a swift newbie. I have an old app in obj-c, I would like to translate it to swift. Despite what I read, I am not quite sure how to use the convert to swift feature in Xcode. Can some one give me some guidances? Thanks. I am mainly confused about how the .h and .m on the obj-c side merge into one .swift file. In the .h file, I have a lot of variables and IBOutlets and IBActions declared. How does these all translate to the swift side. Thanks

Comment: There's a "convert to Swift" feature in Xcode?

Comment: This is, with no offense intended, too broad of a question. But, IMHO, don't be tempted by the allure of the automated third-party translation tools, as they generally generate code that is much worse than you could get if you rewrote it yourself. I'd suggest spending a little time familiarizing yourself with Swift and once you have a degree of proficiency, tackle the rewrite yourself. And you don't have to do it all at once, but you can theoretically tackle it class by class (though if a small project, doing it all at once diminishes the Objective-C/Swift integration issues).

Comment: The "Convert To Current Swift Syntax" feature in Xcode – if that is what you are thinking of – can convert "older" Swift code (such as Swift 2.2) to "newer" Swift code (such as Swift 3). Xcode can not translate Objective-C to Swift.

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK there is no convert Objective C to swift code feature in Xcode. There is only a convert from Swift X to newer Swift Y features.

That said. The .h file is the header file of your objective c. These are the methods and properties that other objects in your code can call on that specific class.

Swift has a similar feature but its all in the Swift file. If you mark a function as private then its roughly equivalent to a method being in the .m file but NOT in the .h file.

However, when you're just getting started with swift, don't sweat it too much. Use the default func declaration in place of -( declaration in objective c and just forget about the .h file for now. This will expose all functions and properties as if they were in the .h file in Objective C. But while you're getting started, thats the easier, more permissive way. Once you get more experienced you can start marking functions and methods as private and then they will no longer be exposed to other parts of your code.

Comment: Thank you all for the replies :) As I said I am a newbie. Misunderstood the meaning of the convert->convert to current swift syntax. :(

Comment: Not out of the box, you can install Swiftify Xcode extension https://objectivec2swift.com/#/home/xcode-extension/ to achieve conversion from Obj-C to Swift right form Xcode.